# Where to get Cross GCC For Mac OS

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I was wondering where to get Cross GCC for mac, and how to install it.

I have installed the eclipse IDE on mac, and am able to run it, however it asks for a compiler path. To my knowledge I don't have a c++ compiler and I would like to know where to get one from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that it is good practice on this site to *show the own research* when asking. This is to avoid that other people research and propose solutions that you've already unsuccessfully tried. Otherwise, your question might attract downvotes. I suggest you [edit] your question to include that. Also, please be sure to check out our posting guide ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Cross compiler for which target? If Arduino, you can use _Help > Arduino Downloads Manager_ (assuming [Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-c-ide-arduino) is installed).